# Gibt es andere übliche Märchenbeginnformeln neben "es war einmal"?

Tags: regional

Sehr viele Märchen beginnen auf Deutsch mit "Es war einmal", aber ich kenne auch ein Märchen, das anfängt mit "Zu der Zeit, als das Wünschen noch geholfen hat ...".

Gibt es noch andere Beginnformeln und wenn ja, kann man diese dem geographischen Ursprung der Märchen zuordnen?

> Many German fairy tales open with
>   "Es war einmal", but some start with
>   "Zu der Zeit, als das Wünschen noch
>   geholfen hat ...".
>
> Are there any other common
>   introductions? If so, is there a correlation between their use and the geographic origin of the story?

Comment: Recht häufig ist auch „Vor langer, langer Zeit“ oder ähnliches. „Es war einmal“ ist aber wohl der bekannteste Anfang, insbesondere Dank den Brüdern Grimm ;)

Comment: Linguistischer Fachbegriff mit "M" - *Märchenbeginnformel*...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Mir ist beim vermehrten Märchenlesen mal aufgefallen, dass eigentlich nicht so viele Märchen, wie man denken würde (von z. B. [Grimms Märchen](http://www.grimmstories.com/de/grimm_maerchen/list)), tatsächlich mit "Es war einmal" anfangen. Dies trifft aber vor allem für die bekannten unter ihnen zu. Weitere Formeln lassen sich im Link nachschlagen. Z. B. sind mir noch "Vor langen Zeiten", "Es ist nun schon lange her" oder "Es trug sich zu, dass" aufgefallen. Viel mehr zeichnet sich eine Märchenerzählung für mich durch die ständige Verwendung des Präteritums aus.

Comment: Wo kann man über den Link den Märchenanfang sehen? Unter den 10 alphabetisch ersten Märchen fand ich 6, die mit *es war einmal* begannen.

Answer (score 5):

Here are some examples from the 1812/1815 first edition

**1812**

- KHM 1 Es war ein mal
- KHM 3 & 15 Vor einen großen Walde
- KHM 43 Auf eine Zeit
- KHM 47 Dat is nu all lang her ->comes from the Plattdeutsch dialect found in the Meckelenburg-vorpommern area.

**1815**

- KHM 1 Vor alten Zeiten
- KHM 41 Zur Zeit, wo das Wünschen noch geholfen hat
- KHM 61 Zur Zeit da unser Herr noch auf Erden ging
- KHM 68 Ich will euch etwas erzählen

Comment: Welchen Sinn haben die Zahlen am Beginn der Zeilen? Bitte editiere deine Antwort und erkläre was die Zahlen aussagen sollen, oder lösche diese Zahlen. Wenn du Aufzählungen verwendest, setze an den Beginn jedes Auszählungspunktes ein Minus (also »- Punkt« statt »Punkt«) und trenne die ganze Liste oben und unten mit je einer Leerzeile vom restlichen Text ab.

Comment: Noch etwas: Wenn auf Deutsch gefragt wird, dann antworte wenn möglich auch auf Deutsch. Das hier ist ein *Deutsch*-Forum! Siehe auch: https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/a/830/1487

Comment: The number indicates the KHM text number. Will not allow insertion of" #" Should I delete the answer?

Comment: And what is a *KHM text number*? If you use widely unknown abbreviations, please add a definition for this abbreviation.

Comment: KHM bezieht sich auf "Kinder- und Hausmärchen", den ursprünglichen Namen der heute bekannten Grimms Märchen. KHM 1 ist etwa "Der Froschkönig oder der eiserne Heinrich"

Answer (score 4):

Ja, gibt es. Ein Märchen zeichnet sich nicht dadurch aus, dass es mit "Es war einmal" beginnt, sondern dass Fantasy-Elemente wie Riesen, Hexen und gute Prinzen, die Jungfrauen retten, darin vorkommen.

Ein Märchen kann also auch so beginnen:

> Dem Karl sein Sohn, ein Prinz, machte
>   sich eines Tages auf, die Prinzessin
>   von Schloss Verschlossen zu retten

Woher es kommt, dass ein Großteil der Märchen mit "Es war einmal" beginnt, kann ich nicht sagen. Allerdings nehme ich mal an, dass unter anderem die Gebrüder Grimm daran schuld sind und dass es dann "einfach" irgendwann übernommen wurde. Wahrscheinlich soll damit angedeutet werden, dass die Geschichte in einer Welt spielt, die es heute nicht mehr gibt; entweder, um die Geschichte plausibler zu machen oder um die Geschichte weniger gruselig für Kinder zu machen.

Comment: Ich würde ja nach "Tages auf" ein Komma setzen (aber das Kommaregelnpauken in der Schule hab ich boykottiert :D).  Einfach weil "machtes sich eines Tages auf die Prinzessin" etwas, sagen wir mal, auszüglich klingt. ;-)

Comment: @jae: Naja, irgendwo müssen ja die kleinen Prinzen und Prinzessinnen für die nächste Märchengeneration her kommen ;)

Comment: *sondern das Fantasy-Elemente wie Riesen, Hexen und gute Prinzen, die Jungfrauen retten darin vorkommen* Blödsinn. Ein Märchen zeichnet sich durch die für Märchen übliche Handlungsstruktur aus. Mehr dazu unter [wikipedia: Volksmärchen](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volksm%C3%A4rchen)